# R: Is it possible to retrieve a KNN model's predicted Y at a given point?

Tags: r, machine-learning, self-study, prediction, k-nearest-neighbour

I've been asked to compare the predicted value of a GLM fit at a specific point to that of a KNN fit at the same point. However I can't find any code or functions to do this with KNN models. Is it possible to make R output this number?

I'm using package kknn.

Comment: This sounds a bit open-end to me. Did the specify how they meant the kNN, or what k they think of? Do you simply taking k=1 and predict your nearest point? Check the [FNN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/index.html) its function `knn.reg` is what you probably need.

Comment: Looking at that package's manual, it seems to only give a vector of all predicted values. So if I want to know the value at a point not in the vector, I'm guessing I'd be out of luck. This is the same issue as with kknn. I feel I'm missing something.

Comment: Is there something stopping from selecting the point you want from the vector of fitted values?

Comment: It only shows the predicted y values without the corresponding X. Also, since I can't see the X's, it could be that the true predicted Y is not exactly equal to one of the values in the vector of fitted values. With linear regression we simply need to plug a value into F(x) to calculate Y, if you see what I mean..